# How to use helm charts to deploy using google cloud build

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am in the learning phase of Kubernetes and want to set up the CI/Cd pipeline for my project. I am using google cloud and have the following elements are ready

1. 3 Node cluster is deployed on google cloud
2. Github has been integrated with google cloud build to trigger the build.
3. I am using `helm` to maintain my K8s templates.
4. `cloudbuilld.yaml` is developed to compile the docker image and push it to google container registry.

I am stuck at - Once my cloudbuild.yaml is done with building the docker image and pushed it to the registry, how do I use helm to upgrade the chart?

Here is my sample `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/kubernetes-amit-test/github.com/0xvoila/apache/phoenix:$SHORT_SHA", "."]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/kubernetes-amit-test/github.com/0xvoila/apache/phoenix:$SHORT_SHA"]

  - name: "alpine/helm:latest".   --- It is not working 
    args: ["helm","upgrade","mychart","image", "gcr.io/kubernetes-amit-test/github.com/0xvoila/apache/phoenix:$SHORT_SHA"]
```

My Question is

1. How can I use helm to upgrade the latest charts.
2. As I am new to Kubernetes, it is even the best practice for K8s deployment? Do people even use helm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I use helm to upgrade the latest charts.

There is already default helm exist : **gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-builders-helm**

```
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-builders-helm'
  args: ['upgrade', '--install', 'filebeat', '--namespace', 'filebeat', 'stable/filebeat']
```

For managing chart version you should check the : https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/helm/manage-charts

Helm cloud builder [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm)

> As I am new to Kubernetes, it is even the best practice for K8s
> deployment? Do people even use helm?

Helm is the best way to manage it instead of using any other.

i would suggest checking out the `helm atomic`

```
helm upgrade --install --atomic
```

which will also auto rollback deployment if it's failing in K8s.

> --atomic                       if set, upgrade process rolls back changes made in case of failed upgrade. The --wait flag will be set
> automatically if --atomic is used

[Read more](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/)

**Extra :**

Instead of fixing the GCR name, you can also use variables this template will work across the **branches** of across repo also.

```
- id: 'build test core image'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
- id: 'push test core image'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA']
```

**Update :**

Adding GKE cluster details to Cloud build

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['apply', '-f', 'deployment.yaml']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE}'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER}'
```

i am using the **kubectl** **apply** but you can add these **environment** **variables** to your **helm** step.

[File location](https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild/blob/main/cloudbuild-deployment.yaml)

**Full file**

```
substitutions:
    _CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE: us-central1-c  # default value
    _CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER: standard-cluster-1      # default value
steps:
- id: 'set test core image in yamls'
  name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['apply', '-f', 'deployment.yaml']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE}'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER}'
```

Comment: Hi @Harsh : Thanks for exhaustive answer, one question regarding helm, when I will issue the upgrade command from cloud-builders-helm then how helm would know where is my cluster ? I am sure there must be some configuration. Can you help me with that

Comment: sure updated answer for same. please feel free to comment still have any doubt. you can set the cluster config to environment variables

Comment: Harsh, I tried but help image but got the following error `Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/kubernetes-amit-test/cloud-builders-helm:latest not found:`

Comment: try this image once : `gcr.io/rimusz-lab1/cloud-builders-helm`

Comment: Hi Harsh, it has worked .. I have got stuck in some other step. I will try to resolve it my own. I will accept your answer soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Harsh, I worked through this - Actually the main issue is with the helm image. To make it work - I cloned the cloud-builders repo and build the helm image and upload it on google cloud. Then in my cloudbuild I refer it as `REGION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_IDhelm/helm`

Comment: got that ideally, it should be available by default.